# Fastest LP free Library in python, with copy Function

Tags: python, or-tools, pulp, linear-optimization

i have written a linear optimization problem in PuLP and it works great.. but the solving time is huge, so i have tried another optimization library google-OR that is x10 time fister but has a big issue that doesn't allow to deepcopy the problem (while PuLP does) and for me is very important due to the fact that my optimization problem is a search procedure so i have to change some values in the constraints and solve the problem again and again (hundreds of time). So there is any python library faster than PuLP that allows the copy of the model? Or there is a way to copy an LP problem in google-OR?

Comment: You can export to protobuf and import again. You can also modify the model in place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.